# Paho-mqtt max clients

Tags: mqtt, paho

I have a question regarding mqtt-paho and the possibility to create 10K clients using multiprocessing based process.
This is my code for now (I am using multi-processing based process to create threads):

```python
import multiprocessing
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import threading
import logging
import math
import thingsboard_objects as Things
import random
import datetime
import numpy as np
import sys
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

init_time = time.time()
disconnected = 0

def Connect(client, broker, port, token, keepalive, run_forever=False):
    connflag = False
    delay = 5
    print("connecting ",client)
    badcount = 0  # counter for bad connection attempts
    while not connflag:
        print(logging.info("connecting to broker " + str(broker)))
        # print("connecting to broker "+str(broker)+":"+str(port))
        print("Attempts ", str(badcount))
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            client.username_pw_set(token)
            client.connect(broker, port, keepalive)
            time.sleep(1)
            connflag = True

        except:
            pass
            #client.badconnection_flag = True
            #logging.info("connection failed " + str(badcount))
            #time.sleep(5)
            #badcount += 1
            #if badcount >= 3 and not run_forever:
            #    return -1
            #    raise SystemExit  # give up

    return 0


def wait_for(client, msgType, period=1, wait_time=15, running_loop=False):
    """Will wait for a particular event gives up after period*wait_time, Default=10
seconds.Returns True if succesful False if fails"""
    # running loop is true when using loop_start or loop_forever
    client.running_loop = running_loop  #
    wcount = 0
    while True:
        logging.info("waiting" + msgType)
        if msgType == "CONNACK":
            if client.on_connect:
                if client.connected_flag:
                    return True
                if client.bad_connection_flag:  #
                    return False

        if msgType == "SUBACK":
            if client.on_subscribe:
                if client.suback_flag:
                    return True
        if msgType == "MESSAGE":
            if client.on_message:
                if client.message_received_flag:
                    return True
        if msgType == "PUBACK":
            if client.on_publish:
                if client.puback_flag:
                    return True

        if not client.running_loop:
            client.loop(.01)  # check for messages manually
        time.sleep(period)
        wcount += 1
        if wcount > wait_time:
            print("return from wait loop taken too long")
            return False
    return True


def client_loop(client, broker, port, token, keepalive=600, loop_function=None,
                loop_delay=10, run_forever=False):
    """runs a loop that will auto reconnect and subscribe to topics
    pass topics as a list of tuples. You can pass a function to be
    called at set intervals determined by the loop_delay
    """
    client.run_flag = True
    client.broker = broker
    print("running loop ")
    client.reconnect_delay_set(min_delay=1, max_delay=12)

    while client.run_flag:  # loop forever

        if client.bad_connection_flag:
            break
        if not client.connected_flag:
            print("Connecting to " + broker)
            if Connect(client, broker, port, token, keepalive, run_forever) != -1:
                if not wait_for(client, "CONNACK"):
                    client.run_flag = True  # break no connack
            else:  # connect fails
                client.run_flag = False  # break
                print("quitting loop for  broker ", broker)

        client.loop(0.01)

        if client.connected_flag and loop_function:  # function to call
            loop_function(client, loop_delay)  # call function

    time.sleep(1)
    print("disconnecting from", broker)
    if client.connected_flag:
        client.disconnect()
        client.connected_flag = False


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(buf)


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        client.connected_flag = True  # set flag
        for c in clients:
          #print("connected OK")
          pass
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=", rc)
        file1 = open("bad_connections.txt","a")#append mode 
        file1.write("Bad connection Returned code=%s \n" % rc) 
        file1.close() 
        client.loop_stop()


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    client.connected_flag = False  # set flag
    print("client disconnected ok")


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("In on_pub callback mid= ", mid)

def pub(client, loop_delay):

    rmd_current = round(random.uniform(0.6, 50.0), 2)
    rmd_pressure = round(random.uniform(0.6, 50.0), 2)
    global init_time
    if time.time() - init_time >= 3600:
        rmd_mnc = round(random.uniform(5.0, 30.0), 2)
        rmd_sdc = round(random.random(), 2)
        rmd_mnp = round(random.uniform(5.0, 30.0), 2)
        rmd_sdp = round(random.random(), 2)

        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry',
                       '{"Current": "%s","Pressure": "%s","Str": "12341","Stp": "12340","AL1": "~","AL2": "~",'
                       '"AL3": "~","AL4": "~","AL5": "~","AL6": "~","AL7": "~","AL8": "~"}' % (rmd_current, rmd_pressure))
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry',
                       '{"MnC": "%s", "SdC": "%s", "Str": "2554","Stp": "2554", '
                       '"MnP": "%s", "SdP": "%s"}' % (rmd_mnc, rmd_sdc, rmd_mnp, rmd_sdp))

        init_time = time.time()
    else:
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry',
                       '{"Current": "%s","Pressure": "%s","Str": "12341","Stp": "12340","AL1": "~","AL2": "~",'
                       '"AL3": "~","AL4": "~","AL5": "~","AL6": "~","AL7": "~","AL8": "~"}' % (rmd_current, rmd_pressure))
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(loop_delay)

def Create_connections(n_clients, threads):
    for i in range(len(n_clients)):
        cname = "client-" + n_clients[i]["name"]
        t = int(time.time())
        client_id = cname + str(t)  # create unique client_id
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id)  # create new instance
        n_clients[i]["client"] = client
        n_clients[i]["client_id"] = client_id
        n_clients[i]["cname"] = cname
        broker_p = n_clients[i]["broker"]
        port = n_clients[i]["port"]
        token = n_clients[i]["token"]
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
        client.on_publish = on_publish
        #client.on_message = on_message
        t = threading.Thread(target=client_loop, args=(client, broker_p, port, token, 600, pub))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

def main_loop(clients_loop):

    mqtt.Client.connected_flag = False  # create flag in class
    mqtt.Client.bad_connection_flag = False  # create flag in class

    threads = []
    print("Creating Connections ")
    no_threads = threading.active_count()
    print("current threads =", no_threads)
    print("Publishing ")
    Create_connections(clients_loop, threads)

    print("All clients connected ")
    no_threads = threading.active_count()
    print("current threads =", no_threads)
    print("starting main loop")
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            no_threads = threading.active_count()
            print("current threads =", no_threads)
            for c in clients_loop:
                if not c["client"].connected_flag:
                    print("broker ", c["broker"], " is disconnected" , c["name"])
                    file2 = open("disconnects.txt","a")#append mode 
                    file2.write("broker %s is disconnected %s \n" % (c["broker"], c["name"])) 
                    file2.close()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    #sys.exit("A connection was dropped")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("ending")
        for c in clients_loop:
            c["client"].run_flag = False
        
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # In case the user is using a demo version or local version of thingsboard
    things_location = input("What type of thingsboard installation are you working with (demo/local)? ")

    if things_location == "demo":
        type_install = "demo.thingsboard.io"
        header = Things.get_credentials(things_location)
    elif things_location == "local":
        computer = input("Which computer? ")
        type_install = "cseetprj%s.essex.ac.uk:8080" % computer
        broker = "cseetprj%s.essex.ac.uk" % computer
        header = Things.get_credentials("local", type_install)
    else:
        print("Error: Installation not supported")

    my_devices = Things.get_devices_id(header, type_install)
    
    clients = []
    for device in my_devices:
        device_info = {"broker": broker, "port": 1883, "name": device["name"],
                       "token": Things.get_device_token(device["id"]["id"], header, type_install)}
        clients.append(device_info)
        
    print(len(clients))
    time.sleep(5)
    if len(clients) >= 200:
        print("Splitting devices to multiprocess")
        split_by = math.ceil(len(clients) / 250)
        split_clients = np.array_split(clients, split_by)

    jobs = []
    for idx, client_portion in enumerate(split_clients):
        print("Starting process for portion %s" % (idx + 1))
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_loop, args = (client_portion,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
        
    for job in jobs:
      print("Ending process")
      job.join()
```

When testing only with 1K devices, for some reason I get some rc=3 (this number varies and I don't know why), and another clients end up disconnecting (also don't know why). Is there something wrong with the code? I am planning to try to send data for up to 10K devices but I cant even get to establish 1K constant connections.

The specs of the machine where I have the IoT platform (that receives the connections) are the following:

- Processor: Intel Core i5-3570 CPU @3.40GHz x 4
- RAM: 8GB
- Disk Size 500GB

Comment: couple thoughts ... does the MQTT broker allow 10k connections from one IP address? .... why do you require 10k simultaneous clients on one device?

Comment: Hi, I believe that it is possible (from thingsboard documentation on how many devices can handle, still waiting to verify if from one IP address is also possible). I want to simulate 10K devices sending data to the platform, they will send data every 10 seconds and then I will see cassandra performance.

Comment: No not really, since the limits are likely to be specific to python's threading/network implementation. Also you only deleted the other question once I'd pointed out you shouldn't post to multiple sites. And as we said on the original question, at least start by using standard existing load generation tools before trying to write your own, at this point you are testing 2 divergent values (the test harness and the broker...)

Comment: You should also look at the broker logs as this is most likely to give the reason why clients are being disconnected.